# jquery mobile CSS class is not applying on input field

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I want the .ui-input-text class to be applied to the input field. But is not being applied. I am using jquery mobile class for the text input. The border radius is not changing unless I applied inline with CSS. Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'RNS Camelia';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            src: local('RNS Camelia'), url(http://localhost/codeigniter/fonts/RNS_Camelia.otf);
        }

        .ui-btn {
            width: 40% !important;
            height: 15px !important;
            border-radius: 50px !important;
            text-align: center !important;
            background-color: #D6DE23 !important;
            font-family: 'RNS Camelia', serif !important;
        }

        .login_button {
            margin-left: 20px !important;
            text-align: center !important;
        }

        .ui-page {
            background-image: url('../codeigniter/images/background.jpg') !important;
            width: 100%;
            background-size: 100% 100%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        ​ .ui-input-text {
            border-radius: 50px !important;
        }

        .user_pass {
            text-align: center!important;
            color: white!important;
            font-family: 'RNS Camelia', serif!important;
            font-size: 16px!important;
            height: 20px!important;
        }

        .text_input_wrap {
            margin-right: 15px !important;
        }

        .bottom_links {
            color: white!important;
            font-family: 'RNS Camelia', serif!important;
            text-decoration: none !important;
        }
    </style>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div class="ui-content" data-role="main">
            <img border="0" src="<?php echo $this->config->base_url();?>   images/logo_only.png" alt="Logo Bar Express" style="margin:0px;width:313px;display:inline;height:142px;float:left;" />
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>



            <div class="ui-grid-b">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <div class="user_pass">Username</div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <div class="user_pass">Password</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="ui-grid-b">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <div class="text_input_wrap">
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"> </div>

            </div>


            <input type="password" id="password" name="password">

            <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <div class="login_button">
                        <input type="submit" value="LOGIN">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Seems to be working here: http://jsfiddle.net/397sd7zL/. Just copied and pasted your code.

Comment: The input fields are suppose to have the same border radius as the logging button. This not happening.

Comment: the login button is .ui-input-btn not text. ui-input-txt is put on text fields. That's why you are not seeing that border-radius.

Comment: Do you what me to edit the CSS to make the input fields the same border radius as login button?

Comment: Yes, the border-radius of 50px is  modifying the .ui-input-text class, but the input field is not taking that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here do this bit of code at the bottom of your own stylesheet.

**[FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dowomentfart/397sd7zL/2/)**

```
.ui-input-text{
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I loaded my stylesheet externally with the css in the head section and I discovered there was an extra character in front .ui-input-text producing an error thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `<style>` block to your `body` from `Head` section.
Why because jquery mobile uses ajax, so it will not load anything from `Head`.

Read more [here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/faq/scripts-and-styles-not-loading.html)

Comment: This is not working I think has to do with the jquery mobile.

Comment: Thanks for the input. But this applies to css in the head loaded after the page is created or loaded for the first time not when the page is loaded for the first time as it was happening.